# Linq Sub Query (SELECT in SELECT)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity, subquery

I have got a native join sub query problem in MySQL Entity. SQL code is;

DB structure is;

**tbl_urunler_kod**
**id**, **kod**
 - 1, pkod1
 - 2, pkod2
 - 3, pkod3

**tbl_urunler**
**id**, **kod_id**
 - 1, 1
 - 2, 2
 - 3, 3
 - 4, null
 - 5, null
 - 6, null
 - 7, null
 - 8, null
 - 9, null

`SELECT (SELECT k.kod FROM tbl_urunler_kod k WHERE k.id=t.kod_id) AS kod FROM tbl_urunler t`

its giving 9 records.

I try this,

```
 var SQL = (from p in SME.tbl_urunler
                   from k in SME.tbl_urunler_kod
                              where k.id == p.kod_id
                   select new
                   {
                       kod = k.kod
                   });
```

its returning only 3 records. Because tbl_urunler_kod have got only not null 3 records. Other 6 records is null. I wanna see all records. How can i do this.

And i try this;

```
var SQL2 = (from p in SME.tbl_urunler
                       select new
                       {
                           kod = (from k in SME.tbl_urunler_kod where k.id == p.kod_id select new { k.kod })
                       });
```

Its giving this error;

```
'System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.CompensatingCollection`1[f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]]' türündeki nesne 'System.String' türüne atılamadı.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: 'System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.CompensatingCollection`1[f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]]' türündeki nesne 'System.String' türüne atılamadı.
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was created a little simulatin for this.
Please look the results;

```
public class tbl_urunler_kod
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Kod { get; set; }
    public tbl_urunler_kod() { }
    public tbl_urunler_kod(int _ID, string _Kod)
    {
        _ID = ID;
        _Kod = Kod;
    }
}

public class tbl_urunler
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Adi { get; set; }
    public int KodID { get; set; }
    public tbl_urunler() { }
    public tbl_urunler(int _ID, string _Adi, int _KodID)
    {
        _ID = ID;
        _Adi = Adi;
        _KodID = KodID;
    }
}

public List<tbl_urunler_kod> L_tbl_urunler_kod = new List<tbl_urunler_kod>();
public List<tbl_urunler> L_tbl_urunler = new List<tbl_urunler>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Fill();
    Result1();
    Result2();
    Result3();
    Result4();
    Result5(); //Its working
    Result6(); //Its working
    Result7(); //Its working
}

public void Fill()
{
    #region tbl_urunler_kod filling
    L_tbl_urunler_kod.Add(new tbl_urunler_kod { ID = 1, Kod = "Kod_1" });
    L_tbl_urunler_kod.Add(new tbl_urunler_kod() { ID = 2, Kod = "Kod_2" });
    L_tbl_urunler_kod.Add(new tbl_urunler_kod() { ID = 3, Kod = "Kod_3" });
    #endregion

    #region tbl_urunler filling
    L_tbl_urunler.Add(new tbl_urunler() { Adi = "Urun_1", ID = 1, KodID = 1 });
    L_tbl_urunler.Add(new tbl_urunler() { Adi = "Urun_2", ID = 2, KodID = 2 });
    L_tbl_urunler.Add(new tbl_urunler() { Adi = "Urun_3", ID = 3, KodID = 3 });
    L_tbl_urunler.Add(new tbl_urunler() { Adi = "Urun_4", ID = 4 });
    L_tbl_urunler.Add(new tbl_urunler() { Adi = "Urun_5", ID = 5 });
    L_tbl_urunler.Add(new tbl_urunler() { Adi = "Urun_6", ID = 6 });
    L_tbl_urunler.Add(new tbl_urunler() { Adi = "Urun_7", ID = 7 });
    L_tbl_urunler.Add(new tbl_urunler() { Adi = "Urun_8", ID = 8 });
    L_tbl_urunler.Add(new tbl_urunler() { Adi = "Urun_9", ID = 9 });
    #endregion
}

public void Result1()
{
    Response.Write("<h1>Result 1</h1>");

    var SQL = (from p in L_tbl_urunler
               from k in L_tbl_urunler_kod
               where k.ID == p.KodID
               select new
               {
                   p.Adi,
                   kod = k.Kod
               }); //result count = 3 record;

    foreach (var i in SQL)
    {
        Response.Write(i.Adi + " - " + i.kod + "<br/>");
    }

    Response.Write("<br/><hr/>");
}

public void Result2()
{
    Response.Write("<h1>Result 2</h1>");

    var SQL = (from p in L_tbl_urunler
               from k in L_tbl_urunler_kod
               where k.ID == p.KodID || p.KodID == 0
               select new
               {
                   p.Adi,
                   kod = k.Kod
               }); //result count = 21 record;

    foreach (var i in SQL)
    {
        Response.Write(i.Adi + " - " + i.kod + "<br/>");
    }

    Response.Write("<br/><hr/>");
}

public void Result3()
{
    Response.Write("<h1>Result 3</h1>");

    var SQL = (from p in L_tbl_urunler
               let LKod = L_tbl_urunler_kod.Where(k => k.ID == p.KodID).Select(x => x.Kod)
               select new
               {
                   p.Adi,
                   kod = LKod
               }); //result count = 9 record;

    foreach (var i in SQL)
    {
        Response.Write(i.Adi + " - " + i.kod + "<br/>");
        //System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,System.String]
    }

    Response.Write("<br/><hr/>");
}

public void Result4()
{
    Response.Write("<h1>Result 4</h1>");

    var SQL = (from p in L_tbl_urunler
               select new
               {
                   p.Adi,
                   kod = (from k in L_tbl_urunler_kod where k.ID == p.KodID select new { k.Kod })
               }); //result count = 9 record;

    foreach (var i in SQL)
    {
        Response.Write(i.Adi + " - " + i.kod + "<br/>");
        //System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,<>f__AnonymousType3`1[System.String]]
    }

    Response.Write("<br/><hr/>");
}

public void Result5()
{
    Response.Write("<h1>Result 5</h1>");

    var SQL = (from p in L_tbl_urunler
               select new
               {
                   p.Adi,
                   kod = L_tbl_urunler_kod.Where(k => k.ID == p.KodID).Select(x => x.Kod).FirstOrDefault()
               }); //result count = 9 record;

    foreach (var i in SQL)
    {
        Response.Write(i.Adi + " - " + i.kod + "<br/>");
    }

    Response.Write("<br/><hr/>");
}

public void Result6()
{
    Response.Write("<h1>Result 6</h1>");

    var SQL = (from p in L_tbl_urunler
               select new
               {
                   p.Adi,
                   kod = (from k in L_tbl_urunler_kod where k.ID == p.KodID select new { k.Kod }).FirstOrDefault()
               }); //result count = 9 record;

    foreach (var i in SQL)
    {
        Response.Write(i.Adi + " - " + i.kod + "<br/>");
    }

    Response.Write("<br/><hr/>");
}

public void Result7()
{
    Response.Write("<h1>Result 7</h1>");

    var SQL = (from p in L_tbl_urunler
               let LKod = L_tbl_urunler_kod.Where(k => k.ID == p.KodID).Select(x => x.Kod).FirstOrDefault()
               select new
               {
                   p.Adi,
                   kod = LKod
               }); //result count = 9 record;

    foreach (var i in SQL)
    {
        Response.Write(i.Adi + " - " + i.kod + "<br/>");
    }

    Response.Write("<br/><hr/>");
}
```

**Result 1**

```
Urun_1 - Kod_1
Urun_2 - Kod_2
Urun_3 - Kod_3
```

**Result 2**

```
Urun_1 - Kod_1
Urun_2 - Kod_2
Urun_3 - Kod_3
Urun_4 - Kod_1
Urun_4 - Kod_2
Urun_4 - Kod_3
Urun_5 - Kod_1
Urun_5 - Kod_2
Urun_5 - Kod_3
Urun_6 - Kod_1
Urun_6 - Kod_2
Urun_6 - Kod_3
Urun_7 - Kod_1
Urun_7 - Kod_2
Urun_7 - Kod_3
Urun_8 - Kod_1
Urun_8 - Kod_2
Urun_8 - Kod_3
Urun_9 - Kod_1
Urun_9 - Kod_2
Urun_9 - Kod_3
```

**Result 3**

```
Urun_1 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,System.String]
Urun_2 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,System.String]
Urun_3 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,System.String]
Urun_4 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,System.String]
Urun_5 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,System.String]
Urun_6 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,System.String]
Urun_7 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,System.String]
Urun_8 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,System.String]
Urun_9 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,System.String]
```

**Result 4**

```
Urun_1 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,<>f__AnonymousType31[System.String]]
Urun_2 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,<>f__AnonymousType31[System.String]]
Urun_3 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,<>f__AnonymousType31[System.String]]
Urun_4 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,<>f__AnonymousType31[System.String]]
Urun_5 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,<>f__AnonymousType31[System.String]]
Urun_6 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,<>f__AnonymousType31[System.String]]
Urun_7 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,<>f__AnonymousType31[System.String]]
Urun_8 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,<>f__AnonymousType31[System.String]]
Urun_9 - System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[test+tbl_urunler_kod,<>f__AnonymousType31[System.String]]
```

**Result 5**

```
Urun_1 - Kod_1  
Urun_2 - Kod_2  
Urun_3 - Kod_3  
Urun_4 -  
Urun_5 -  
Urun_6 -  
Urun_7 -  
Urun_8 -  
Urun_9 -
```

**Result 6**

```
Urun_1 - { Kod = Kod_1 }  
Urun_2 - { Kod = Kod_2 }  
Urun_3 - { Kod = Kod_3 }  
Urun_4 -  
Urun_5 -  
Urun_6 -  
Urun_7 -  
Urun_8 -  
Urun_9 -
```

**Result 7**

```
Urun_1 - Kod_1  
Urun_2 - Kod_2  
Urun_3 - Kod_3  
Urun_4 -  
Urun_5 -  
Urun_6 -  
Urun_7 -  
Urun_8 -  
Urun_9 -
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
var SQL = (from p in SME.tbl_urunler
               from k in SME.tbl_urunler_kod
                          where k.id == p.kod_id || p.kod_id == null
               select new
               {
                   kod = k.kod
               });
```

**Update** here's what I could understand from your comments:

```
var q = from u in SME.tbl_urunler
    join k in SME.tbl_urunler_kod on u.kod_id equals k.id into JoinedUK
    from k in joinedUK.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        id = u.id,  
        kod = k != null ? k.kod : null
    }
```

Comment: Its very cute solution. But its only resolving this null and not null fields. But what it has got another records. I have to always add some values SQL sentence. For exaple; 

`k.id == p.kod_id || p.kod_id == null || p.kod_id == bla bla || p.kod_id == null bla bla`

Comment: @AhmetYETİK: I do not understand your question. If you want to return all p.Kod_id, then there's no need to set the `where` clause. based on your comment, you should remove `where k.id == p.kod_id || p.kod_id == null`. Otherwise, p.kod_id is either equal to k.id or null.

Comment: Sorry for my lang. I wanna try explaning it another way; this sentences 

`where (k.id == p.kod_id)` - returns 3
`where (k.id == null)` - returns 0
`where (k.id != null)` - returns 27
`where (k.id == p.kod_id && p.kod_id ==null)` - returns 0

It has got some problems. Because its joining tbl_urunler and tbl_urunler_kod ... But it will be when tbl_urunler returning a row look tbl_urunler_kod and return kod.

thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Kamyar. Its giving some errors.

`The name 'k' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.
Expected contextual keyword 'equals'`

Comment: In my opinion maybe i need Linq let command. It was like that;

`var SQL = from p in SME.tbl_urunler
                      let kod = SME.tbl_urunler_kod.Where(k => k.id == p.kod_id).FirstOrDefault().kod
                      select new
                      {
                          kod
                      };`


its giving this error. 

`System.NotSupportedException.`

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @AhmetYETİK: Sorry I forgot to use `equals`. please run my updated query again.

Answer (score 1):

this is LingtoSql lambda expression

```
    var query = SME.tbl_urunler.Where
                (x=>x.tbl_urunler_kod.id == x.kod_id  || 
                x.kod_id == null).Select(x=>new {x.id})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers @esi .I will try it on evening.
I like lambda sentences. Its more understandable. :)

Comment: Hello Ahmet lambda experssion is very very good on the linq so try learn it.

Comment: Dear @esi;

But its only resolving this null and not null fields. But what it has got another records. I have to always add some values SQL sentence. For example; `k.id == p.kod_id || p.kod_id == null || p.kod_id == bla bla`

is there any other global resolution via Lambda. Thanks again.

Comment: Ahmet i could not clearly understood your comment. but if i don't mistake
this is very simple, you can use any variable on the where statement in the lambda experssion
for example ( int count= 100; dataContext.TableName.Where(x=>x.id == count); )

Comment: im looking your code now. Its joining good. But it will be when tbl_urunler returning a row look tbl_urunler_kod and return tbl_urunler colums and give 'kod'. 

it should be something like this;

`(from p in SME.tbl_urunler
                       select new
                       {
                           kod = (from k in SME.tbl_urunler_kod where k.id == p.kod_id select new { k.kod })
                       });`


thanks.